# Catch specific exception instead of "Exception ex"

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, try-catch

I'm inserting data to a database and I guess some kind of exceptions might occur here, possible more than one?

ussually I used to write something like this:

```
try
{
 //Execution code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 // log error and throw it
}
```

And I think it's better to catch some specific exception instead of `(Exception ex)` something like this:

```
try
{
    // my possibly bad code which inserts data to db
    var someEntity = CreateEntityFromDTO(someDTO);

    _context.SomeThing.Add(someEntity);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
catch(MySpecificException mse)
{
   // log error and throw it 
}
```

What might be best practice when it's about catching exception while inserting data to db ?

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: What "best practice" are you asking about here?  If you want to catch a specific exception to respond in a specific way, you are certainly encouraged to do that.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: There are no best practices.  If catching a general `Exception` works best in your case, then do it.  Otherwise, tailor your exception handling behavior to deal with more-specific exception types.

Comment: Are there any types of exceptions you want to catch somewhere else? If not, catch them all right there. You can have a different handler for your specific type though: `try { /* do stuff */ } catch (MySpecificException mse) { /* handle mse */ } catch (Exception ex) { /* handle anything else */ }`. But don't be more specific unless that solves some particular problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your `SpecificExceptions` inherit from another higher level `DatabaseException` and handle all `Database Exceptions` in one catch clause like

```
public class DatabaseException : Exception {}
public class MySpecificException : DatabaseException {}
public class YetAnotherDBSpecificException : DatabaseException {}
try
{
   // insert data.
}
catch(DatabaseException dbEx)
{
   // A database exception occured.
   Console.Log(dbEx.Message);
}
catch(Exception other)
{
   // Non db exception occured.
   Console.Log(other.Message);
}
```